# Cross g++ compiler linker error

Tags: c++, c, arm, eclipse-cdt, atmel

I am using [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) to cross compile a g++ project for an ARM processor. I am using the yagarto toolchain in a Windows environment. I have no issues with C projects, but with C++ I keep receiving the errors:

```
libc.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
abort.c:63: undefined reference to `_exit'

libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:58 undefined reference to `_sbrk'

libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
signalr.c:61: undefined reference to `_kill'
```

as well as:

```
undefined reference to `_getpid'
undefined reference to `_write'
undefined reference to `_close'
undefined reference to `_fstat'
undefined reference to `_isatty'
undefined reference to `_lseek'
undefined reference to `_read'
```

From looking around it looks like I have a linker issue. I tried to add the linker flash.ld. It is from a GCC example for my ARM development kit from Atmel Studio. It is not helping. Is there a linker for g++ somewhere? Do I have another issue?

Here are my build options:

```
make all
Building target: Foo
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ -nostartfiles -T C:/Users/kempsa/eclipse_workspace/Foo/flash.ld -o"Foo"  ./HALTimer1.o ./Main.o
```

I have the source files Main.cpp, HALTimer1.cpp and the header file Haltimer.h. The main file only includes the header file. The header file only defines a class for the HALTimer with one variable. I don't believe these affect the error. I believe the error is solely from tying to build a g++ project without the correct linker file.

Here is the content of the linker file:

```
/**
 * \file
 *
 * \brief Flash Linker script for SAM.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2011-2012 Atmel Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *


    OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
    OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
    SEARCH_DIR(.)

    /* Memory Spaces Definitions */
    MEMORY
    {
        rom (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00400000, LENGTH = 0x00040000 /* flash has two banks, one bank = 256K */
    ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00010000 /* sram, 64K */
    }

    /* The stack size used by the application. NOTE: you need to adjust  */
    __stack_size__ = DEFINED(__stack_size__) ? __stack_size__ : 0x2000;

    /* Section Definitions */
    SECTIONS
    {
        .text :
        {
            . = ALIGN(4);
            _sfixed = .;
            KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
            *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
        *(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7)
        *(.rodata .rodata* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)

        /* Support C constructors, and C destructors in both user code
           and the C library. This also provides support for C++ code. */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.init))
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __preinit_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
        __preinit_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __init_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array))
        __init_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(0x4);
        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .ctors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.ctors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __fini_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.fini_array))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        __fini_array_end = .;

        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .dtors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.dtors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _efixed = .;            /* End of text section */
    } > rom

    /* .ARM.exidx is sorted, so has to go in its own output section.  */
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_start = .);
    .ARM.exidx :
    {
      *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > rom
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_end = .);

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;

    .relocate : AT (_etext)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _srelocate = .;
        *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
        *(.data .data.*);
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _erelocate = .;
    } > ram

    /* .bss section which is used for uninitialized data */
    .bss (NOLOAD) :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sbss = . ;
        _szero = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = . ;
        _ezero = .;
    } > ram

    /* stack section */
    .stack (NOLOAD):
    {
        . = ALIGN(8);
          _sstack = .;
        . = . + __stack_size__;
        . = ALIGN(8);
        _estack = .;
    } > ram

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _end = . ;
}
```

Complete compiler output:

```
Building target: Foo
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ -nostartfiles -T C:/Users/kempsa/eclipse_workspace/Foo/flash.ld -o"Foo"      ./HALTimer.o ./Main.o
c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\stdlib/../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/stdlib/abort.c:63: undefined reference to `_exit'
c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c:58: undefined reference to `_sbrk'
c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:61: undefined reference to `_kill'
c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_getpid_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:96: undefined reference to `_getpid'
c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/reent/writer.c:58: undefined reference to `_write'
c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `_close_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/reent/closer.c:53: undefined reference to `_close'
c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/reent/fstatr.c:62: undefined reference to `_fstat'
c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/reent/isattyr.c:58: undefined reference to `_isatty'
c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `_lseek_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/reent/lseekr.c:58: undefined reference to `_lseek'
c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/reent/readr.c:58: undefined reference to `_read'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Foo] Error 1
```

Comment: OK, so, if you think it's a linker file problem, then list the content of your `C:/Users/kempsa/eclipse_workspace/Foo/flash.ld` linker command file.

Comment: Try `-v` option with both gcc and g++, look at the difference.

Comment: verify that the objects and libraries you are trying to link together are for the same architecture by inspecting them with `objdump -af *.o *.a`

Comment: I am having trouble getting objdump -af *.o *.a to work properly... But the linker file was built for gcc. Is there a way to port it to g+? I haven't been able to find an example project that uses g++ only gcc. Is there a generic linker file for g++ that I can modify to suit my project?

Answer (score 0):

Add the linker options -Wl,--gc-sections and the problem should be resolved

Comment: You should not post this as an answer - rather include it in your question. Done that for you now.